# nested struct with array

Tags: c++, initialization, nested-class

Please, help me to create a nested struct with an array. How do I fix this code?

```
class CMain
{
    public:
        CMain();
        ~CMain();

    private:
        struct
        {
            CCheckSum() : BufferSize(500) {memset(Buffer, 0, BufferSize);}
            const int BufferSize;
            char Buffer[BufferSize];
        }SmallBuffer;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static arrays need to know their length at compile time, or you need to dynamically allocate memory:

```
struct CCheckSum
{
    CCheckSum()
    : BufferSize(500),
      Buffer(new char[BufferSize])
    {
        memset(Buffer, 0, BufferSize);
    }
    ~CCheckSum() { delete[] Buffer; } // Note the use of delete[]!
    const int BufferSize;
    char* Buffer;
}SmallBuffer;
```

You're probably better off using [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) though:

```
struct CCheckSum
{
    CCheckSum() : Buffer(500, 0) {}
    std::vector<char> Buffer;  // A std::vector keeps
                               // track of its size enternally
}SmallBuffer;
```

Comment: I intended to use array because I need to fill it with consecutive blocks of raw data bytes. Push_back() it will cause reallocation which I want to avoid. If I declare a vector of 500 bytes how do I copy, say , blocks of 100, 200 and 200 bytes into it one after another without putting them byte-by-byte with [] operator?

Comment: Actually, come to think of it, `std::(tr1::)array`, not `std::vector` is the correct thing to use here, since the size is (supposed to be) a compile-time constant.

Comment: Two things:  1) You wouldn't be pushing back, you've already got an array of 500 bytes.  2) Vectors are stored as contiguous memory, so you can use them like raw-pointer arrays.  &Buffer[0] is a pointer to the beginning of the array which can be used in c-style memory functions.

Comment: If he has access to it, std::(tr1::)array is a good choice too.  If not, vector is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Even though you declared `BufferSize` as `const`, at class scope this does not declare a compile-time constant, which is needed for declaring array sizes in C++, but a constant data member, which, once set in the constructor, cannot be changed anymore for the lifetime of the instance (but can still be different for each instance).

Two solutions:
Make

1. `BufferSize` `static const` at class scope, or
2. (just) `const` at namespace scope (including global scope).

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem related to the nesting.

Arrays have constant size.  Either make BufferSize constant or use a std::vector instead of a char[].

Comment: But I declared BufferSize as const int. And I use raw buffer since I need to do some simple and quick work with raw data coming from network.

Comment: You need to make it static as well.

Answer (score 0):

Array size cannot be changed at run time. It should be known at compile time itself. 
You can use std::vector for this use case.
Also, the struct name should be given before writing the constructor with the  name CCheckSum.

```
struct CCheckSum
        {
            CCheckSum() : ....
```